# Unit Testing - Using Image as Resource in Test Project

Tags: wpf, image, unit-testing, resources

One part of a project that I am writing unit tests for extracts data from a jpeg header.

I would like to create a unit test that tests this extraction, using a known image (so I can test the known properties of that image).

It seems logical to me that this sample image be kept in the testing project as a Resource, but I am not sure how to do so.  If it was a WPF project, I'd simply use the pack syntax.

Is there a Best Practice for something like this (or, even, something that would work)?

Thanks,
wTs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is based on @Matthew Manela's posted answer, which pointed me in the (or, perhaps more appropriately, one) right direction.  It feels a bit kludgey to me, but it works.

First, set the image as a Content resource, with Copy Always.

Then, use the following helper function (used by different tests):

```
private string GetValidFileName()
{
    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
    return Path.Combine(fileInfo.DirectoryName, @"Resources\Sample.jpg");
}
```

Comment: I think Matthews solution is actually neater, as it means your unit tests are *only* dependent on the assembly, not on any other resources

Comment: I agree, except in this case I wanted the ability to swap out the image.

Answer (score 7):

You can include the image in your test project as an embedded resource.
Then you can use the following code to get the stream of that image:

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("TestProject.TestImages.myImage.png");
```

For more information see [this link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324567)

Comment: +1 for putting me on the right path.  I didn't want the Stream, but rather an absolute file path, but I did use reflection as you suggested.  See my posted answer.